# Unable to toggle between Radio Button after authenticating user using MFP 8.0

Tags: ionic2, ibm-mobilefirst

I am building hybrid mobile app using Cordova **6.5**, Ionic **3.1.1** and MObileFirst Foundation 8.0 (Server : **8.0.0.00-20170220-1900** and Client SDK : **8.0.2017033009**). I have created a Yes/No radio button using ionic's ion-list as follow:

**list.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
      <ion-list radio-group formControlName="wsQuestion1">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="1"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>No</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="0"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Following is the code which I am using for login:

```
WLAuthorizationManager.login('UserLogin', data).then(
      () => {//success handler
          this.openNextPage();
      },
      () => {//failure handler
        console.log("Error handler");
        alert('ALERT_ERR_REQUEST_PROCESSING_FAILED');
      }
    );
```

If I navigate to this page from "Menu --> List" then I am able to toggle between Yes/No and the ration button is getting selected. But If I, enter username/password , click login, then when I reach to this page after authentication, I am not able to toggle between Ratio buttons.

I have created an app which reproduces this scenario. You can get it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/37dmaictkj4w6dh/MyIonic3Project4.zip?dl=0).

Do the following in order to reproduce:

1. Download, unzip, and navigate to project root directory
2. Run `npm install` on command prompt
3. Run `cordova platform add` on command prompt
4. Run `ionic serve` on command prompt
5. Run `cordova run android`
6. When app open on the device then enter (test as username/password)
7. You can try tapping the Yes/No button.

Here is how it looks into my device:

[image]

Comment: Removing the form makes the radio button work fine. So this issue does not seem to be related with MFP. I suggest you raise this up ionic.

Comment: @S.A.NortonStanley I have already opened up this issue with MFP and they are investigating it. They said, they have replicated it in there environment and they should be  providing root cause soon. For the point you mentioned, on a contrary if I remove MFP call then everything works fine.

Comment: So ideally this happens when a form submit is performed, not the MFP call. I make a submit to my rest end point which has nothing to do with MFP i still face the same issue.

Comment: I tried the same but did not face this issue. CAn you provide the app sample?

Comment: I tried the same sample shared with MFP to debug the issue.

Comment: @S.A.NortonStanley I sent the request using XMLHttpRequest and it is working fine for me. 

`let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
          console.log('Success XMLHttpRequest');
          __this.openNextPage();
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "my-rest-end-point", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    xhttp.send();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the login part of code to following:

```
WLAuthorizationManager.login('UserLogin', data).then(
      () => {//success handler
        console.log("is angular zone ",NgZone.isInAngularZone());
          this.ngZone.run(()=>{
          console.log("is angular zone ",NgZone.isInAngularZone());
          this.openNextPage();
        });          
      },
      () => {//failure handler
        console.log("Error handler");
        alert('ALERT_ERR_REQUEST_PROCESSING_FAILED');
      }
    );
```

The reason it was behaving like this was because the “success handler” of WLAuthorizationManager was running outside of Angular Zone and that’s why the changes were not getting detected.

To fix the issue, I have wrapped the call of “openNextPage” method into “[this.ngZone.run(() => { ... })](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html#!#run-anchor)” and it worked perfectly then.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to thread timing in ionic code. An issue has been raised and can be found here : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/1547. As a temporary workaround, a small timeout of 2 milliseconds can be added to the function "checkandupdateview" that ensures the view to be updated correctly.

**UPDATE**
The issue still has nothing to do with MFP whether ionic accepts or not. It is a thread timing which could as well happen with any plugin not necessarily only MFP. Still, here is a workaround to get your code running with a small timeout in  ***ionic code***  only.

Modify the "checkandupdateview" ionic function in your main.js (which will be in the build folder) to the below snippet. As you can see all it does it is to add a small pause to ionic's view rendering.

```
function test2()
{
    setTimeout(function(){ 
    }, 1);  
}
/**
 * @param {?} view
 * @return {?}
 */
function checkAndUpdateView(view) {
    try{
    if( view.component.navCtrl._ids == 1 && view.component.navCtrl.id == "n4"
    )
    {
        test2();
    }            
    }catch(e){}
    Services.updateDirectives(view, 0 /* CheckAndUpdate */);
    execEmbeddedViewsAction(view, ViewAction.CheckAndUpdate);
    execQueriesAction(view, 33554432 /* TypeContentQuery */, 268435456 /* DynamicQuery */, 0 /* CheckAndUpdate */);
    callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst(view, 1048576 /* AfterContentChecked */ |
        (view.state & 1 /* FirstCheck */ ? 524288 /* AfterContentInit */ : 0));
    Services.updateRenderer(view, 0 /* CheckAndUpdate */);
    execComponentViewsAction(view, ViewAction.CheckAndUpdate);
    execQueriesAction(view, 67108864 /* TypeViewQuery */, 268435456 /* DynamicQuery */, 0 /* CheckAndUpdate */);
    callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst(view, 4194304 /* AfterViewChecked */ |
        (view.state & 1 /* FirstCheck */ ? 2097152 /* AfterViewInit */ : 0));
    if (view.def.flags & 2 /* OnPush */) {
        view.state &= ~2 /* ChecksEnabled */;
    }
    view.state &= ~1 /* FirstCheck */;
}
```

Please revert in case there are still issues.

Thanks!

Comment: If I add the timeout then the app seems to be hanged after its done loading and I am not even able to enter username and password.

Comment: Please run it on the emulator. The app will hang on a device as though the timeout is very small, it still will slow down the processes on the device as this particular function will be called multiple times. This is only to show that the actual issue is occurring due to ionic thread timing mismatch and not due to MFP login.

Comment: Agreed, but If I don't use MFP then it works properly. In my view MFP is causing this somehow. Also, they have closed the but which you have opened with the comment that this is not their issue.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari Please find the update above and update if it works for you or not.

Comment: I did not understand this piece of code: view.component.navCtrl._ids == 1 && view.component.navCtrl.id == "n4" ?

Comment: These are the views that are used for page rendering. The "HomePage" and "ListPage" have internally been given this id by ionic. To implement this in your application, you might have to debug and find out how ionic names your particular application's views.

Comment: @Keerthi..All the pages have id assigned to them as "n4". I have tried your solution but I am still having the same issue. I am checking into Android device.

Comment: @Keerthi...I posted my answer below and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @PrerakTiwari Thank you for sharing the solution! Glad you got it working :)